# "area" vs. "areal" to describe an estimate of space

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

E.g. an areal/area estimate of corn in Iowa

"Areal" is commonly found in remote sensing and land cover literature ([this article](http://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_1992_czaplewski_r001.pdf), for example). Which is most appropriate to describe the estimation of corn area?

Comment: Please use *area* as some people (e.g. me) often misread *areal* as *a-real* rather than *area-l*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal conversation, you would say it an estimation of "corn acreage". Or the "area" corn is grown in Iowa. "Areal" appears to be an adjective form of area, but I have never heard it used that way.

Comment: unfortunately it's "corn square kilometers" that I'm estimating. I've generalized the question.

Comment: @metasequoia: Nevertheless, *acreage* would be understood, and there is a case for saying that 'the acreage is 1 million sqaure kilometres' is correct, though it might be momentarily puzzling.

Comment: @metasequoia Every field has its' technical jargon, if this is for professionals in the field of remote sensing and/or land cover then I suppose you might choose "areal". Otherwise, it's likely to be confused with "aerial".

Comment: @TimLymington: Great point. I had always assumed that it was like 'mileage' in that it necessarily invoked the measurement unit.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as *geomatician* (or one expert in geomatics, which includes remote sensing):

**areal** -- Of or related to a two-dimensional spatial or geographical extent, but not necessarily involving a quantity. Also *regional*.

**area** -- 1. A two-dimensional spatial or geographical extent. Also *region*. 2. Measurement of same. Also *size*.

[apologies for any lack of correct dictionary style]

So "an area estimate of corn" or "an area estimate for corn" are correct, but "an estimate of corn area" or "an estimate for corn area" are perhaps better.